# flatten nested json array with named collections

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

given the below json

```
[
    {
        id: 'myId1',
        value: 'Tree View top level 1',
        fetchedChildren: []
    },
    {
        id: 'myId2',
        value: 'Tree View top level 2',
        fetchedChildren: [
            {
                id: 'myId3',
                value: 'Tree View second level 1',
                fetchedChildren: []
            },
            {
                id: 'myId4',
                value: 'Tree View second level 2',
                fetchedChildren: []
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

where nested named "fetchedChildren" collections could go on for infinity

Is there a simple way to flatten it to single array like this?

```
[
    {
        id: 'myId1',
        value: 'Tree View top level 1',
    },
    {
        id: 'myId2',
        value: 'Tree View top level 2',
        
    },
    {
        id: 'myId3',
        value: 'Tree View second level 1',
    },
    {
        id: 'myId3',
        value: 'Tree View second level 2',
    },
]
```

I've seen a lot of examples that do this to nested objects that dont have named collections, but I haven't seen or could figure out how to do this in this scenario

Comment: Will it always only be 1 layer deep, or more?

Comment: more - could go on forever theoretically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursion is the way for any depth-first search on a tree:

```js
let arr=[
    {
        id: 'myId1',
        value: 'Tree View top level 1',
        fetchedChildren: []
    },
    {
        id: 'myId2',
        value: 'Tree View top level 2',
        fetchedChildren: [
            {
                id: 'myId3',
                value: 'Tree View second level 1',
                fetchedChildren: []
            },
            {
                id: 'myId4',
                value: 'Tree View second level 2',
                fetchedChildren: []
            },
        ]
    },
];

function flatten(a){
    var result=[];
    for (let e of a) {
       result.push({id:e.id,value:e.value})
       result=result.concat(flatten(e.fetchedChildren));
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(flatten(arr));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could take a `flatMap` method and get all children by destructuing the children from the object.

```js
var getFlat = ({ fetchedChildren, ...o }) => [o, ...fetchedChildren.flatMap(getFlat)],
    data = [{ id: 'myId1', value: 'Tree View top level 1', fetchedChildren: [] }, { id: 'myId2', value: 'Tree View top level 2', fetchedChildren: [{ id: 'myId3', value: 'Tree View second level 1', fetchedChildren: [] }, { id: 'myId4', value: 'Tree View second level 2', fetchedChildren: [] }] }],
    flat = data.flatMap(getFlat);

console.log(flat);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want: (do not use recursion because you could overflow the callstack as you say it could had a infinity number of layers)

```js
const ar = [{
    id: 'myId1',
    value: 'Tree View top level 1',
    fetchedChildren: []
}, {
    id: 'myId2',
    value: 'Tree View top level 2',
    fetchedChildren: [{
        id: 'myId3',
        value: 'Tree View second level 1',
        fetchedChildren: [{
            id: 'myId5',
            value: 'Tree View thrid level 1',
            fetchedChildren: []
        }]
    }, {
        id: 'myId4',
        value: 'Tree View second level 2',
        fetchedChildren: []
    }]
}];


for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    if (ar[i].fetchedChildren.length) {
        ar.push(...ar[i].fetchedChildren);
    }
    delete ar[i].fetchedChildren;
}
console.log(ar);
```

Comment: You have to use recursion because the nesting can go arbitrarily deep.

Comment: That's exactly the opposite, because the nesting can go arbitrarily deep you should not use the recursion because the callstack could be arbitrarily overflowed.

Comment: Well. The data size has to be managed by the coder elsewhere. Moreover, modern compilers may optimize tail recursion. From what I can tell, your code can only handle two levels.

Comment: I think my code could handle any number of level (I edited the example with an extra third level)

Comment: ok...I got it. Yours is a breadth-first approach, isn't it? It is apparently more memory-efficient.

Comment: It's also destructive, which would worry me a lot.  I much prefer code which does not mutate its input.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce to run a recursive extractor.

```js
const data = [
        {
            id: 'myId1',
            value: 'Tree View top level 1',
            fetchedChildren: []
        },
        {
            id: 'myId2',
            value: 'Tree View top level 2',
            fetchedChildren: [
                {
                    id: 'myId3',
                    value: 'Tree View second level 1',
                    fetchedChildren: []
                },
                {
                    id: 'myId4',
                    value: 'Tree View second level 2',
                    fetchedChildren: []
                },
            ]
        },
    ]
    
    const extract = (acc, item) => {
      const value = Object.keys(item)
        .filter(k => k !== 'fetchedChildren')
        .map(k => ([k, item[k]]))
        .reduce((res, [k,v]) => ({...res, [k]: v}), {})
      const children = item.fetchedChildren.reduce(extract, [])

        
      return [...acc, value, ...children]
    }

    const result = data.reduce(extract, [])

 console.log(data)
 console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameter destructuring can help us write a simple recursion for this case:

```js
const flatten = ([{fetchedChildren = undefined, ... rest} = {}, ... xs]) => 
  fetchedChildren == undefined
    ? []
    : [rest, ... flatten ([... xs, ... fetchedChildren])]

const ar = [{id: 'myId1', value: 'Tree View top level 1', fetchedChildren: []}, {id: 'myId2', value: 'Tree View top level 2', fetchedChildren: [{id: 'myId3', value: 'Tree View second level 1', fetchedChildren: [{id: 'myId5', value: 'Tree View thrid level 1', fetchedChildren: []}]}, {id: 'myId4', value: 'Tree View second level 2', fetchedChildren: []}]}];

console .log (flatten (ar))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

And a tail-recursive variation is not much more complex:

```js
const flatten = ([{fetchedChildren = undefined, ... rest} = {}, ... xs], res = []) => 
  fetchedChildren == undefined
    ? res
    : flatten ([... xs, ... fetchedChildren], [...res, rest])
```